# How to replace a file in the upgrade process

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to build a new "update tool" for one of my programs.
Delphi XE5.
Firebird 2.5

how to replace a UDF (the file is in use)?
how to replace a file (the file is in use)?

Comment: Your current question is confusing and some people might vote down/vote to close. I suggest you edit your question to get to the point of what you're actually asking. It seems like you're specifically interested in how to replace a file that is in use making the first 3/4 of your question irrelevant. (And please don't talk about "10000% in use"; that makes absolutely no sense: a file is in use or it's not.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace a file which is in use by renaming it to a temporary name and then copying the new file. Applications having the file opened will not be affected by the rename (the file handle still pointing to the original file). Of course, once an application close the file and reopen it, it will actually close the old file and open the freshly copied file. This mays affect the application depending on what it does.

Comment: That won't work if file is on the FAT32 partition.